# Scrollbar on lightbox showing for just a moment;

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, lightbox

Please take a look at this site: *removed per request*

When you click Learn More, the Fancybox lightbox window pops up and looks fine, but when you click the right arrow on the lightbox, a scrollbar shows up for just an instant (it reaches all the way to the top of the doctor's picture).  This is happening on Chrome and Safari.

I can't figure out what code to write to *not* show that scrollbar. The content will never be long enough to need a scrollbar (except on mobile, etc).  Another option would be to just have the scrollbar stop at the top of the content container (not go all the way up to the top of the dr's picture).  Please help if you can; it would be much appreciated!!  I'm a newb to jQuery/Javascript.  Thank you!!

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: post your relevant code with your question and don't ask people to click on unknown links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to solve this with CSS. Set `overflow: hidden` on the container div. This will hide any content that overflows the container, so use with care.